# Javascript not working on HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

So have a script named script.js:

```
var newLabel = '';
$('#payment_amount').on('change', function(){
    $('#change_label').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
    switch(this.value){
        case 'junior':
            newLabel = 'Junior Account';
            break;
        case 'premium':
            newLabel = 'Premium Account';
            break;
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

I'm calling it to my html file by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

My code for select is this:

```
<select id = "payment_amount">
    <option class="junior" value="junior">Junior</option>
    <option class="premium" value="premium">Premium</option>
</select>

<label id="change_label">Hello</label>
```

I already tried directly putting my js code to the html by adding it to the  tag but I'm still not having any luck. Where did I go wrong with this one?

Comment: $ is jquery.. Pease add the jquery script as cdn or  from  your local.

Comment: Working fine on my end. What do you mean by not working? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal hmmm sorry for the newb question but how can I add that to my script?

Comment: @Eddie the label doesnt change to anything even though i change the select value? i have no idea what i am missing.

Comment: Did you add jquery?

Comment: try to add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @zoenightshade : you can add the script <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to your script part or copy the contents from the above script ,have a local file and refer the path of that file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `jquery`library to your code, Have it locally (or) point to any CDN like below,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Here is a working version of your code,

```
https://jsfiddle.net/uqo84q71/
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
 var newLabel = ''; $('#payment_amount').on('change', function(){ $('#change_label').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value switch(this.value){ case 'junior': newLabel = 'Junior Account'; break; case 'premium': newLabel = 'Premium Account'; break; } }).trigger('change'); 
</script>
```

If its work then check the src attributes (script.js) is it one same folder-

Answer (score 0):

First of all add Main jquery file.
[Jquery file](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

2ndly add this replace this code.

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
       var newLabel = '';
        $('#payment_amount').on('change', function(){
        $('#change_label').text(newLabel);
    switch(this.value){
    case 'junior':
        newLabel = 'Junior Account';
        break;
    case 'premium':
        newLabel = 'Premium Account';
        break;
   }
   }).trigger('change');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your HTML a little. See where I've included the scripts. Try it and check if it works now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <select id = "payment_amount">
        <option class="junior" value="junior">Junior</option>
        <option class="premium" value="premium">Premium</option>
    </select>
    <label id="change_label">Hello</label>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case ,

Check these 2 things .

1) Import Jquery cdn

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

2)Check the file of `script.js` where it was added i.e `path` of it. Might be path related issues.

Hope this helps..!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it on head:-

```
## <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id = "payment_amount">
    <option class="junior" value="junior">Junior</option>
    <option class="premium" value="premium">Premium</option>
</select>
<label id="change_label">Hello</label>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

##

Answer (score 0):

```
var newLabel = '';
$('#payment_amount').on('change', function(){
    $('#change_label').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
    switch($('#payment_amount').val()){ // add jquery-3.2.1.min.js and change this
        case 'junior':
            newLabel = 'Junior Account';
            break;
        case 'premium':
            newLabel = 'Premium Account';
            break;
    }
})
```